# User management in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, wcs

I stored several layers on GeoServer. In the near future, users should have access to certain layers, e.g. User_1 should only have access to Layer_1, Layer_2, Layer_3, User_2 should only have access to Layer_2, Layer_3, Layer_4 and so on.

How can I realize this?

I already read the user/roles/group documentation but I haven't found a solution for "multiple users and multiple, but overlapping layers".

Or should I create a single workspace for each user? Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 3):

GeoServer can apply [access to individual layers based on groups of users](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html) so all you need is to define the group that can access each layer and place the users that can access it in to the correct groups.

If you have some sort of system as to who can see what then it should work out quite simply, if access is arbitrary then you will end up with a complex system.

You may find it useful to work through the [GeoSolutions tutorial on access controls](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/security/users_roles.html).